# Derivative of natural log vs base 10 log

Tags: calculus

Consider the logarithmic function with base $10.$ 
$$
y=\log{\left(x\right)}
$$
 wherein the derivative with respect to $x$ is: 
$$
f'\left(x\right)=\frac{1}{x}
$$
Now consider the natural logarithmic function:
$$
y=\text{ln}\left(x\right)
$$
wherein the derivative with respect to $x$ is:
$$
f'\left(x\right)=\frac{1}{x}
$$
What I fail to understand, is why there is no ``scaling'' factor
here. These are separate functions- it does not intuitively make sense
to me that both would grow at the same rate with respect to $x.$
In other words, for a given increase in $x,$ $\log{\left(x\right)}$should
grow slower than $\text{ln}(x),$ as it is of base 10. Am I missing
something?

Comment: Don't use a mixture of `$\text$` and `$\ensuremath$` to format functions since it doesn't render. Instead, simply use a backslash before the function, i.e., `$\log x$` for $\log x$.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The simple answer is that your derivative for $\log_{10}$ is incorrect. In fact
$$\log_{10} x=\frac{\ln x} {\ln 10}$$
Thus you can see that the derivative is indeed smaller, being $\frac1{x\ln 10}$.

Comment: Thank you so much! I am in Economics, where people use ln(x) an log(x) interchangeably, when they really mean ln(x).

Comment: @ChinG I use $\ln$ and $\log$ interchangeably as well, which is why I refused to write $\log$ to mean $\log_{10}$.

Comment: @ChinG The base $10$ logarithm is essentially useless in most cases. It's unnatural, quite literally, and it's mostly ceased to be relevant since we stopped using slide rules.

Comment: Thank you, Matt. .

Comment: In pure math, you only need a natural logarithm so you can get away with saying "$\log$" for all cases. But in applied math (especially in areas like chemistry, re. pH), the base-10 log is still ubiquitous so it is best to be clear which log is intended. If there is any chance of confusion, you can use $\lg$ or $\log_{10}$ for the base-10 log and $\ln$ for the base-e log.

Comment: One can use the term common logarithm for $\log_{10}$. For people who do not have the luxury of enjoying higher mathematics base 10 is indeed common. The word *unnatural* seems bit harsh. +1

Answer (score 2):

There **is** a scaling factor. It turns out that$$\log_{10}'(x)=\frac1{\log(10)x}$$and not $\frac1x$, which is what you wrote.

More generally,$$\log_a'(x)=\frac1{\log(a)x}.$$

Comment: Thanks a lot. Very helpful.

Comment: I thought the log term was in the denominator.

Comment: @Randall Yes, it is. I've edited my answer. Thank you.

Comment: It might be better to specify that "$\log 10$" is the natural log, not base-10 log, since this is the opposite of the OP's notation.

Answer (score 1):

I respectfully dispute Matt Samuel’s answer.

It is not wrong because it is fairly common for $\log$ to mean the natural logarithm as well as $\ln$. Just look at [Wolfram|Alpha](https://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=natural%20logarithm).

Comment: The OP's title explicitly states that this is a distinction between the natural and base-10 logarithms.

Comment: @Jam I don’t think it’s “explicit”; I think it’s possible that ChinG might have misunderstood something from context(s).